# What's wrong with this java for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I'm trying to see what are some cool things i can do with a for loop.
Here's a simple code to print all numbers divisible by 321 between 10_000 and 100_000.

but it doesn't work:

```
for(int i=10000;i<=100000 && i%321==0;i++){
  println(i);
}
```

wasn't it true that i can put conditional statement between the second and third semicolon?
this just outputs nothing, so i'm assuming there's no i values true.

Comment: If `i = 10000`, does `i % 321 == 0`?

Comment: Body of the for loop only executed when the condition is `true`. is `i<=100000` _and_ `i%321==0` going to be true when `i=10000`?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the *syntax,* just that your *condition* is never `true.` If there was something wrong with the syntax the compiler would have told you so.

Answer (score 6):

The loop will stop as soon as `i % 321 == 0` is false, which it will be right off the bat. Try:

```
for (int i = 10000; i <= 100000; i++) {
  if (i % 321 == 0) {
    println(i);
  }
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 10000 + (10000 % 321); i <= 100000; i += 321) {
  println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the condition of your loop.

```
when (i = 10000)

i % 321 = 10000 % 321 = 49
So the condition i % 321 == 0, is false
```

you need to try something like this, in order to work

```
for (int i = 10000; i <= 100000; i++) {
  if (i % 321 == 0) {
    println(i);
  }
}
```